How to describe what the matrix exponential is (not)?
It is known that, in general, for two matrices $A$ and $B$, $\mathrm{e}^A \mathrm{e}^B \ne \mathrm{e}^{A+B}$. Is there a word to denote this? I'm looking for something like "nonlinear", but that would mean that $\mathrm{e}^{A+B} \ne \mathrm{e}^A+\mathrm{e}^B$.

What about not being a homeomorphism?

@AnotherUser Do you mean homomorphism?

@NoahSchweber Yes! Thanks.

The term you're looking for is homomorphism (specifically, monoid homomorphism).
Fix $n>1$, and let $M_{add}$ and $M_{mult}$ be the monoids of $n$-by-$n$ (real) matrices with respect to matrix addition and matrix multiplication respectively. The statement that $e^Ae^B\not=e^{A+B}$ in general is the observation that $X\mapsto e^X$ is not a homomorphism from $M_{add}$ to $M_{mult}$. In general, a homomorphism between two monoids $(A,\star)\rightarrow (B,*)$ is a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that $f(a \star a')=f(a)*f(a')$ and which additionally sends the identity element of $A$ to the identity element of $B$ (an earlier version of this question made a really stupid error at this point - that's what happens when you try to do math at 4:30 AM!).

You took the wrong neutral element. We have $e^0 = 1$. The monoid structure is relevant here, or actually the group structure. By general theory $e^a$ is invertible, so we have a map $\exp : \mathrm{M}_n \to \mathrm{GL}_n$. This is the "natural codomain", also when thinking about the generalization to Lie groups.

@MartinBrandenburg Oh my goodness. Fixed! (Note to self: don't do math at 4:30 AM ... at least, not where others can see the results!)

No worries, you are not alone.
